# Display the city name which has most number of branches

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, count

I have tried to get city name which has most number of branches .

```
select C.City_name ,count(B.B_Name) 
from tblcity C
inner join
tblBranch B
on c.city_id=B.City_id
group by C.City_name
order by count(B.B_Name) desc
```

Above code will give me the count of branches for particular city . 
Please help me solve to get city name which has most number of branches

Comment: I think you need `SELECT TOP 1 ...`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT
    City_Name, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c.City_name,
        COUNT(b.B_Name) cnt,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(b.B_Name) DESC) dr
    FROM tblcity c
    INNER JOIN tblBranch b
        ON b.city_id = c.City_id
    GROUP BY c.City_name
) t
WHERE dr = 1;
```

Using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` would be another option here, but that is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: on c.city=b.city_id

Answer (score 3):

you can add `TOP 1` to your query

```
select TOP 1 C.City_name ,count(B.B_Name) 
from tblcity C
inner join
tblBranch B
on c.city_id=B.City_id
group by C.City_name
order by count(B.B_Name) desc
```

Comment: Top 1 will give one top result . but other city can have same count also .where the result fails .

Comment: @sampathacharya You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in this case.  But there are still arguments for using dense rank, e.g. if you want to also get the second highest, etc.

Comment: @sampathacharya I understood that from your question you only want one city as a result. If you had asked the question as plural, I could add WITH TIES too. If you want to get the correct answer you should ask the correct question.